# How to determine sample size of rated objects for scale development

Tags: probability, survey, sample, scale-parameter

I am currently looking into developing a scale to measure a latent construct. I believe the latent construct is a property of conversation sequences. The scale I am developing has 4 *a priori* defined factors with about 6 items each. We are looking to recruit ca. 250 participants who will use the scale approximately 5 times for 5 rated objects (conversation sequences) in a single session. The sample of "rateable" objects will be larger than 5 and divided into 5 different categories defined *a priori*. The objects will be drawn at random such that from each category, 1 object will be drawn (no replacing). While the division into categories ensures some level of comparability between the objects each participant will rate, I have no way of estimating the variance between "rateable objects" occurring within these categories. I assume that the validity of the scale will increase with a larger sample size of "rateable" objects. I also assume that the reliability of the scale will decrease with a larger sample size of "rateable objects" as overlap of rated objects across participants will decrease.

My questions are the following: What rationale can I follow to simultaneously maximise validity (by increasing the sample size of rateable objects as much as possible) and reliability (by decreasing the sample size of rateable objects as much as possible)? Is there any literature I can look into?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the rationale behind doing this over the span of five time periods?

Comment: Thanks for the question and the opportunity to clarify! The recruited participants will complete the prototype scale for 5 different objects in one session, one after the other. There are no different time periods planned.